# Third where statement in MySQL breaks query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

In the statement below, you can see a commented outline. When I uncomment that line, the statement returns no results. If I leave the line commented I get the results shown in the image, which are correct.

```
select 
`movies`.`id` as 'movie_id', 
`movies`.`title` as 'movie_title', 
`cnt_lists`.`id` as 'cnt_list_id',
`cnt_lists`.`list_id`,
`cnt_lists`.`listable_id`,
`cnt_lists`.`listable_type` 
from `movies` 
inner join `cnt_lists` 
on `movies`.`id` = `cnt_lists`.`listable_id` 
where `movies`.`has_poster` = '1' 
and `cnt_lists`.`list_id` in ('3285') 
# and `cnt_lists`.`listable_type` = 'App\Models\Movie' 
order by `order` desc
limit 1;
```

[image: results with line commented out]

Can anyone shed some light on why the third where statement would result in no results? This is a query I am debugging from a laravel relationship.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems like an encoding problem. You may check if NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES is on, if it's OFF (and this is very likely), then you need to escape "\". This means you need to write the and condition as
`` and `cnt_lists`.`listable_type` = 'App\\Models\\Movie'` ``

Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-literals.html

Update: Just forgot to mention that, please also check if there's any white space around the "App\Models\Movie". If not sure, you could use `like` to avoid the uncertainty: 

`` `cnt_lists`.`listable_type` like '%App\Models\Movie%' ``

or if escaping is needed:

`` `cnt_lists`.`listable_type` like '%App\\Models\\Movie%' ``

Comment: The escaping was the issue. Thanks. Now I just need to figure out how to escape with a Laravel polymorphic relationship.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL returns result set when there are any rows matched otherwise none.

```
  `movies`.`has_poster` = '1' and
  `cnt_lists`.`list_id` in ('3285')
   and `cnt_lists`.`listable_type` = 'App\Models\Movie'
```

If above statement does not return records then try to check if string has same collation.